# Descobrir o usuário que atualizou o wordpress

Tags: wordpress

É possível descobrir qual usuário realizou o update do wordpress?
Sabem se fica algum registro no banco de dados ou algo do tipo? Eu tenho acesso ao FTP, tive que fazer um backup e voltar a hospedagem para 7 dias atrás, algum usuário atualizou o wordpress e limpou toda a programação php que eu havia feito.

Valeu

Comment: Estás a usar um child-theme?

Comment: Sim, tenho um site do grupo e dele consigo selecionar os filhos

Comment: Talvez [este hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/upgrader_process_complete) te possa ajudar